notation in random directed graphs
Suppose I have a directed graph which is simple (no loops or multiple edges with the same direction between nodes) with $n$ nodes.
I am interested in the number of nodes that satisfy the following condition:

are part of a simple cycle, in which no nodes appear more than once.

once removed, the graph contains no more cycles.


Is there a name for this set of nodes?
I am also interested in how to compute the size of this set.
In particular, if the out-degree of each node is independently, randomly drawn from a Geometric distribution with parameter $p$ and the in-degree nodes are chosen uniformly at random, is there a simple way to understand how big this set is? I know some papers in the literature use branching processes.
I know my question is very broadly stated but any way to think about this set is welcomed.

A set of nodes satisfying property 2 (but not necessarily property 1) is called a feedback vertex set. With property 1 added on, it seems to me that such a set might not exist in general. (For example, suppose the directed graph has two cycles with no edges between them; then you need to remove a node from each cycle, but there's no cycle containing both nodes you need to remove.)

Thanks! What if I impose that every node that I remove must be itself in a cycle? That way in your example I would simply remove all nodes.

You mean that you replace property 1 with that requirement? You can do that, but every minimal FVS will already have that property: after all, if a node isn't part of any cycles, there's no point in removing it. Or do you mean that the set you delete is a union of cycles? (Otherwise, I'm not sure why you remove all nodes in the example I gave, as oppose to just two.)
